# How to get different time values from one cell and but it in different cells?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i have an excel sheet like this:

```
   9/2/2018
 3:00PM-11:00PM  
full time(8hr) - 3 PM  
 3:00PM- 4:15PM  
Immediate  
 4:15PM- 4:30PM  
Break  
 4:30PM- 5:45PM  
Immediate  
 5:45PM- 6:15PM  
Break  
 6:15PM- 9:45PM  
Immediate  
 9:45PM-10:00PM  
Break  
10:00PM-11:00PM  
Immediate
```

all this in one cell in the same order 
and i want to take every time range one by one and put it in a different cells?

[the result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaiDE.png)

i want to take the three breaks start time and separated like the picture

Comment: Just to confirm, that's all in one giant cell, line feeds and all?  In the future you'd be better off to store one piece of data per cell, as intended with Excel.  You'll save countless headaches.

Comment: i know but it's an auto generate excel

Comment: you may want to explain in better detail the desired output

Comment: @DisplayName i want to take the three break start time and separated like the picture

Comment: @DisplayName thaks but this will return only the first break , right?

Comment: @displayname thanks a loot  i got it but is there a way to but this result to a specific cell in the sheet not just  Msgbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to take the three break start time

you may try this

```
Function GetBreaksStartTime(txt As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(txt, "Break")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        ReDim startTimes(1 To UBound(arr)) As String
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            startTimes(i) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Split(arr(i), "-")(0), vbLf, ""))
        Next
        GetBreaksStartTime = startTimes
    End If

End Function
```

which you could use in your main code as

```
Dim breaksStartTime As Variant, startTime as variant

breaksStartTime = GetBreaksStartTime(Range("A1").Value2)
For Each startTime in breaksStartTime 
    MsgBox startTime
Next
```

Comment: thaks but this will return only the first break , right?

Comment: No, it returns an array of as many elements as the Breaks in the string and with the start time as their value

Comment: Sorry can you explain it to me in more details, thanks.

Comment: copy the whole code of `Function GetBreaksStartTime(txt As String)` in any module, put the code you find under _"which you could use in your main code as"_ in your main sub, and make it run: it'll pop out as many message boxes as breaks and each showing an initial time

Comment: thanks a loot i got it but is there a way to but this result to a specific cell in the sheet not just Msgbox?

Comment: of course, for instance change `MsgBox startTime` to `Range("B2:").Value = startTime`, and you'll get the current `startTime` in cell B2. But then you have to adjust the target cell at every loop iteration, otherwise you'll overwrite it!

Comment: @displaynamed how to adjust the target cell at every loop iteration?

Comment: well, you could add a `Long` variable (say `Dim i As Long`) to be updated at each iteration (`i = i + 1`) and used in a `Range("B2").Offset(, i).Value = startTime`

Comment: we're now too far from initial issue to handle it in comments: you may want to ask a new question posting your code till now and explaining in proper detail your issue along with examples of what you're getting and what you'd need

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
 =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(2*COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Each **time range** is in its own cell.  We just parse the string on `CHAR(10)` and pick all the odd items.

Comment: @ashleedawg I don't understand.

Comment: Impressive answer.. so short but so functional...  and quicker than it took me to explain how storing data like this takes *so much longer* to deal with.  :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg  Thanks, I fixed the **=**

Comment: @Gary's Student
thanks but i need to take one by one with out separating them , you see this is one day of the weak imagine if i did this formula  for every day

Comment: @abdelrhmanMmdoh I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.  If my answer is not correct, please edit your original question with a sample of the desired output.